# How can I add a role to a user? (devise + cancancan)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cancan, ruby-on-rails-5, cancancan

As I have written in the title I don't know how i can add roles to a user.
I made something like this [tutorial](https://www.sitepoint.com/cancancan-rails-authorization-dance/)
.

my session_controller.rb

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  skip_authorization_check

  def update
    id = params[:id].to_i
    session[:id] = User::ROLES.has_key?(id) ? id : 0
    flash[:success] = "Your new role #{User::ROLES[id]} was set!"

  end
end
```

my ability.rb

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)

      user ||= User.new

     if user.role?(:admin)
       can :manage, :all
     else
       can :read, :all
     end

  end
end
```

and this is in my user.rb model

```
  ROLES = {0 => :guest, 1 => :admin}

  attr_reader :role

  def initialize(role_id = 0)
    @role = ROLES.has_key?(role_id) ? ROLES[role_id] : ROLES[0]
  end

  def role?(role_name)
    role == role_name
  end
```

now I am able to do this like on the [demo page](https://sitepoint-cancan.herokuapp.com/)

Comment: You can directly use `@user.add_role('Admin')` which will add `Admin` role to user if admin role is not present role will be created first

Comment: where I have to put this code? sorry I am new to this

Comment: This seems a little confused - you don't seem to be storing the users role anywhere. Also overriding initialize in an ActiveRecord model like that is likely to lead to problems.

Comment: how can I store the roles into the database? I already have a role model

Comment: i need not repeat myself - i followed Tony Amoyal's role implementation and it worked fantastically fine for me :) good luck: http://www.tonyamoyal.com/2010/07/28/rails-authentication-with-devise-and-cancan-customizing-devise-controllers/